If R is semisimple left Artinian, then R is its own quotient ring.
I am trying to do the following exercises in Hungerford.
If $R$ is semisimple left Artinian, then $R$ is its own quotient ring.
By the Wedderburn-Artin theorem we know that $R$ is isomorphic to sum of matrix ring over division ring, but how can I using this property to prove the above result, or maybe there are different approachs to this question? Thanks you!

What do you mean by "its own quotient ring"? That can't possibly mean $R\simeq R/I$, which is either trivially true ($I=0$) or false (e.g. $R$ is a field).

@freakish It means ring of fractions, in this case, i.e. $RS^{-1}$ where $S^{-1}$ is the set of regular elements. The thing about Artinian rings is that the regular elements are already units..

@rschwieb the ring of fractions, or more generally localization, is well defined over commutative rings only, no?

@freakish No. The construction is also given for noncommutative rings, although the axioms are slightly more involved to make the operations work.  Given any (possibly noncommutative) ring, and a nonempty multiplicative subset which one can say is "right permutable" and "right reversible", one can carry out the construction that works for commutative rings.  (Permutable/reversible are known as the Ore conditions)  Using the subset of regular elements, one can attempt to form a right or left ring of fractions.

This is usually known as the "(left/right) classical ring of quotients."

For an Artinian ring, an element that is not a zero divisor on a side is already a unit.
So, when ones goes to form either ring of quotients for the ring, nothing new is gained, because the set of regular elements is already the set of units.

Oh, I got it! Thanks for your wonderful explanations!!
